# Sendmail and reverse ipv6

Tags: gmail, sendmail, ipv6, freebsd, reverse-dns

I have a big problem with sending e-mails to gmail.

```
( echo Subject: test ; echo ; echo test ) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -Am -i -t -v user@gmail.com
```

Gives me error:

```
[2001:41d0:602:890::] The IP address sending this message does not have a PTR record setup. As a policy, Gmail does not accept messages from IPs with missing PTR records.
```

I have configured Reverse DNS on IPv6, but it seems like my server can't process it right.

My resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

When I asked my server provider for help he told me that server won't answer on port 53 and it gets timeout on trying to get RevDNS.

So... what can I do to get it working?
I tried so many things...

Comment: You need to set the reverse DNS.

Comment: I wrote i have it set

Comment: Yes, you did write that. But it is not set. `Host 0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.9.8.0.2.0.6.0.0.d.1.4.1.0.0.2.ip6.arpa not found: 2(SERVFAIL)` You should contact your service provider (OVH?) for help.

Comment: When i contacted OVH they sent me this:
`;; QUESTION SECTION: ;0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.9.8.0.2.0.6.0.0.d.1.4.1.0.0.2.ip6.arpa. IN PTR`
`;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
0.9.8.0.2.0.6.0.0.d.1.4.1.0.0.2.ip6.arpa. 86400 IN NS domain.pl.`
So what can be wrong then?

Comment: Looks like your DNS server is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command below to locate misbehaving DNS server in the reference/redirection chain:

```
dig +trace -x 2001:41d0:602:890::
```

In you case the last **successful** redirect seems to be from `dns*.ovh.net.` to `avmt2.pl.`.
`avmt2.pl.` seems to be "unresponsive".

```
0.9.8.0.2.0.6.0.0.d.1.4.1.0.0.2.ip6.arpa. 86400 IN NS avmt2.pl.
;; Received 123 bytes from 213.251.188.134#53(dns15.ovh.net) in 60 ms
```